# graph not displaying

Tags: html, sql, laravel, charts, bar-chart

When I run this in a blade.php file it return's a blank white page. I don't know my error can any one help me. or give any suggestion I am new to Laravel.
graph.blade.php

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Bar Chart | Laravel Code</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid p-5">
    <div id="barchart_material" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Product Id', 'Sales', 'Quantity'],

            @php
              foreach($products as $product) {
                  echo "['".$product->id."', ".$product->sales.", ".$product->quantity."],";
              }
            @endphp
        ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Bar Graph | Sales',
            subtitle: 'Sales, and Quantity: @php echo $products[0]->created_at @endphp',
          },
          bars: 'vertical'
        };
        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('barchart_material'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Controller file

```
 public function barChart(){
       $data=Sql::all();
       return view('graph',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

any suggestions would be great!

Comment: check console and share

Comment: follow the tutorial to fix them.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row 1 has 2 columns, but must have 3
    at Object.gvjs_Mk [as arrayToDataTable] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:300)
    at drawChart (dashboard:27)

Comment: Which tutorials

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/